# My while loop isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this simple piece of code, and it works!

```
    $(function () {
    $('form').each(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        form.find('[class^="custAction_"]').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
        form.find('[class^="custAction_4b"]').button('disable');
        form.find('.custSwitch_1').change(function () {
            if (form.find('.custSwitch_1:checked').length) {
                form.find('.custAction_1').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
          } else {
                form.find('.custAction_1').prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
            }
        });
        form.find('.custSwitch_2').change(function () {
            if (form.find('.custSwitch_2:checked').length) {
                form.find('.custAction_2').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
            } else {
                form.find('.custAction_2').prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
            }
        });
        form.find('.custSwitch_3').change(function () {
            if (form.find('.custSwitch_3:checked').length) {
                form.find('.custAction_3').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
            } else {
                form.find('.custAction_3').prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
            }
        });
        form.find('.custSwitch_4').change(function () {
            if (form.find('.custSwitch_4:checked').length) {
                form.find('.custAction_4').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                form.find('.custAction_4b').button("enable");
          } else {
                form.find('.custAction_4').prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                form.find('.custAction_4b').prop("checked", false).button("refresh").button("disable", "disable");

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Knowing that this was repetitive, I thought a "while" loop would work here, so tried this.....

```
        $(function () {
        $('form').each(function () {
            var form = $(this);
            var switchClass = $('form[class^="custSwitch_"]').length;
            form.find('[class^="custAction_"]').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
            form.find('[class^="custAction_4b"]').button('disable');
            var countSw = 1;
            while (countSw < switchClass) {
                form.find('.custSwitch_'+countSw).change(function () {
                    if (form.find('.custSwitch_' + countSw + ':checked').length) {
                        form.find('.custAction_' + countSw).prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                    } else {
                        form.find('.custAction_' + countSw).prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                    }
                }); countSw++
            }
            form.find('.custSwitch_4').change(function () {
                if (form.find('.custSwitch_4:checked').length) {
                    form.find('.custAction_4').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                    form.find('.custAction_4b').button("enable");
                } else {
                    form.find('.custAction_4').prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                    form.find('.custAction_4b').prop("checked", false).button("refresh").button("disable", "disable");

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But, alas it didn't! :-) I know I'm missing something, probably something simple.
the .custSwitch_1, 2, and 3 classes no longer enable and disable the custAction_1, 2, and 3 classes!!

Si.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the variable `countSw` is always 3 because when the code inside the `change` listener is executed, the variable's value is 3.

```
while (countSw < switchClass) {
  form.find('.custSwitch_'+countSw).change(function () {
    doSomething(countSw);
  }); countSw++
}

function doSomething(countSw) {
  if (form.find('.custSwitch_' + countSw + ':checked').length) {
    form.find('.custAction_' + countSw).prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
  } else {
    form.find('.custAction_' + countSw).prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
  }                    
}
```

Note that your `countSw` is being passed as a parameter now.

Comment: Obvious question now... How do I change that? :-) As you can probably tell, I'm not a pro! :-)

Comment: You can switch your first while with mine and then write the function i wrote outside your main function (your loop for forms).  It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I know helping newbs can be tedious for your Java geniuses. :-)